# Magento email being sent in text format instead of HTML

Tags: email, magento

I am abel to test my emails under system>transactional emails.
My email looks correct when i click on the preview button, but when i send it out and recieve the email the email comes in as text only. so all i see is the html code wich deffinitley NOT what i want. Any reason why my email shows up correctly under preview but not when it is actually sent out? 
Below is what my template looks like in the Magento add email template.

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
   <tr>
       <td>
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="email-heading" style="text-align: left;">
                    <p><strong>Name:</strong> {{var data.name}}</p>
                    <p><strong>Email:</strong> {{var data.email}}</p>
                    <p><strong>Telephone:</strong> {{var data.telephone}}</p>
                    <p><strong>Service Requested:</strong> {{var data.service-requested}}</p>
                    <p><strong>Comment:</strong> {{var data.comment}}</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

Comment: show how you send the email. the template is pretty much useless. it's how you build/send the email that counts - e.g. appropriate MIME headers to tell the receiving end that it's an html email.

Comment: I don't have a problem updating my emails. In fact i have not had this problem with updating any of my other Magento store email templates. All other forms appear in html format when opening them up in my email application(This is why i am so confused). This is the only email template i have had that shows up as text in my email application.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having same problem